# Minimum hardware requirement for android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

My system configuration: Intel Pentiunm dual core 1.3GHz with 2GB RAM. I have installed Android Studio but it is sluggish, I'm new in android development. Is upgrading RAM to 4GB help?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I 100% agree

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of November 2020, the [official system requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements) say:

> 4 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended

IMHO, Android Studio will use as much RAM as it can, and your RAM requirements will depend on the size of your project(s) that you are working on. For example, I recently moved from a machine with 16GB RAM to 32GB, owing to Android Studio's memory usage.

Comment: In my experience it is unusable with 4GB RAM. That's the main reason I still stick to Eclipse (On Windows that is, I haven't tried it on any other platform yet).

Comment: I would say that 8GB is the real minimum, and 12GB or higher is far better.

Comment: 4 gb is okay but sometimes it hangs, if I run studio and emulator simultaniously

Comment: 4gb is really low if you also have other stuff opened - chrome, vm, server instances, etc. If not it's usable.

Comment: @ScottBarta: Any chance you can get the official system requirements updated? :-)

Comment: Google lied. Don't believe anything it says. It is unusable with 4gb as min. Better have 8gb+

Comment: They have changed the requirements to 4GB min, 8 max.

Comment: I think you should update this answer. (2020) 8GB RAM minimum, 3GHz processor, Good HDD Speed.

Comment: @Aman: The official system requirements have not changed. Personally, I recommend getting as much RAM as you can afford.

Comment: Don't change the official requirement. But change your recommendation. You are more experienced developer than me and you know it that android requires more. @CommonsWare

Comment: @Aman: I am sorry -- I was not paying attention to my own answer. I have updated it for November 2020.

Comment: @CommonsWare what do u think about procesor?

Comment: @Fortran: Of the three main elements (RAM, SSD, CPU), my guess is that the CPU is the least important for build times. That being said, the faster the CPU, the better. If you plan on using the Android emulator, I *think* that you will have better luck with an Intel CPU rather than an AMD CPU.

Answer (score 25):

I have a laptop with this configuration:

- Core i5
- 4GB RAM DDR3
- HHD 5400RPM speed

And it's very slow.

When I upgrade my system with 8GB RAM and change my HDD with SSD, my speed is much improved.

So, I recommend that, you must at least have 8GB of RAM and Core i5 or Core i7 CPU, with a SSD. Don't use HDD.

---

**UPDATE 27/AGU/2017**

***minimum requirement :***

- SSD
- 8 GB of RAM
- Core i5

***best :***

- SSD
- 16 GB of RAM
- Core i7

---

**UPDATE 31/JUL/2020**

***minimum requirement :***

- 256 SSD
- 12 GB DDR3
- Core i5

***best :***

- 512 SSD
- 24 GB DDR4
- Core i7

Comment: +1 core i5 and i7. This is IDE is becoming more and more resource hog. It is as if this IDE was made using Crytek Engine. The requirements required for this to run optimally matches that of a AAA video game, minus the gfx card of course.

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if in this year 2019 is it still advisable to use core i7 for android studio. My desktop is i7 with 16GB ram but its too slow. Thank you.

Comment: @natsumiyu , do you use of SSD‌ hard drive ? , for cleaning and building your application in androidStudio , SSD‌ require .

Answer (score 10):

I have a computer with 4 GB RAM and Android Studio works very slowly...

I recommend 8 GB minimum.

Answer (score 6):

**This was my experience starting with minimum specs.**
I started with a Dell Optiplex 775 and downloaded and installed [XMeters](https://entropy6.com/xmeters/) to monitor the CPU and RAM. The starting specs was:

```
CPU - Intel Core 2 Duo E6550 2.33GHz
RAM - 4GB

XMeter readings: mostly 100%cpu, 100%ram
```

I used this for about 1 weeks while learning java and android programming. The build times were very long with occasional crashes. I soon realized I was wasting too much time so I upgraded the RAM:

```
CPU - Intel Core 2 Duo E6550 2.33GHz
RAM - 10GB

XMeter readings: mostly 100% cpu,  never crossed 60% ram
```

I used this setup for about 2 months. Build times improved a lot but the cpu was still running at 100% on builds. So I upgraded the cpu.

```
CPU - Intel Quad Core Q9550 2.83GHz
RAM - 10GB

XMeter readings: never crossed 60% cpu,  never crossed 60% ram
```

Note: I was never able to run an emulator, only my phone. Hard Drive was 500gb SATA 7200 RPM.

**Minimum specs would be the last setup but with 6GB ram.**

You can use one of the cpu comparison sites to bench mark your intended purchase against the above minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I have laptop with i3 processor, 8GB RAM and HDD hard drive and it's very slow for Android Studio. Minimum specs of your system should be:
**i5 processor, 8GB RAM and SSD hard drive**

Answer (score 1):

I created my first three android applications using my laptop with these specs:

```
Processor - 5th generation  
Intel Ram - 8 GB  
Graphics - none (Integrated graphics 64MB) 250GB  
SSD (the main reason for my laptop     to run as fast as light)  
Cost - Rs.13,500 [180$] (Second Hand of course)
```

Used my phone for testing apps over ADB wifi (without USB)

Earned more than Rs.80,000 [1100$] from my apps, so my laptop is my best friend.

For the next three years, I will not change my laptop. So you are a college student then do not waste money on a new Laptop.

Because a new Laptop (new windows License + GST + Transportation - Feeling of new + 0 Scratches + warranty + new Battery ) will cost you more than Rs.50,000 [900$] to buy a laptop like mine. Hope you understand.

Comment: Please drop the links to the apps, wanna check it out

Comment: I worked on freelancers (those apps were not on play store), but recently I created a journal app -  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vijayjangid.lifejournalpersonaldiary . I think earning from play store requires good teamwork and a good idea also. So I decided to do freelancing instead of making apps on my own. People usually give 40$ for a simple database app, but Indians give 20$ at most. It actually depends on the app.

Comment: Ohh, that's a very good idea and your app is very good, I'm currently struggling with my 1.6GHz laptop but I'll try my best to work hard and build my apps for the store. They're barely good developers in my country, so I'm struggling hard to do it myself. Your story inspired me, I do appreciate