# development react-native Android Studio CPU ram 4GB

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, sublimetext3, cpu

Currently I develop android app using react-native on ubuntu 16.04 with a low memory computer (4GB RAM) intel core i5:
- IDE - SublimeText3
- Application Testing - Running On Device (Android studio combine with a real device via USB)
- Hot Reloading
- CLI terminal - Android Studio terminal

Until now everything is works well, not slow and I still can open google chrome browser except I can't test my app with another android version using emulator android virtual device.

Is there another best practice where I can develop react-native with RAM 4GB and on the same time run android studio emulator to test my app with different android versions?

I used to try Android studio emulator and in result my computer was really slow - you can check here: [minimum-hardware-requirement-for-android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746027/minimum-hardware-requirement-for-android-studio)

Comment: This is a very unclear question. What exactly are you asking about? And every time you say “best” you’ll have to explain what the definition is. So please edit the question and explain what the exact issue is. Also, i5 and 4GB is now low spec already?

Comment: 4GB and i5 not a low spec. You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746027/minimum-hardware-requirement-for-android-studio btw, thanks for commenting. I've edit the question